# Change variable on main class from external class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, public-method

I want to have to change the var filmAan to false in my Main.as, by the function terug in the external class video01.

This is my Main.as

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.video.*;

public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
    public function Main() 
    {
        trace( "hij werkt" ); 

        btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel1);
        btn_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel2);
        btn_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel3);
        btn_4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel4);
        btn_5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel5);
        btn_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel6);
        btn_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel7);
        btn_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel8);
        btn_9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel9);

        var mc_video01:MovieClip = new video01();
        var mc_video02:MovieClip = new video02();
        var mc_video03:MovieClip = new video03();
        var mc_video04:MovieClip = new video04();
        var mc_video05:MovieClip = new video05();
        var mc_video06:MovieClip = new video06();
        var mc_video07:MovieClip = new video07();
        var mc_video08:MovieClip = new video08();
        var mc_video09:MovieClip = new video09();

        public var filmAan = false;

        function speel1(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 1 werkt");              

                addChild(mc_video01);
                mc_video01.x=340; 
                mc_video01.y=227;
                mc_video01.width=1360;
                mc_video01.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 1 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel2(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {               
                trace("knop 2 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video02);
                mc_video02.x=340; 
                mc_video02.y=227;
                mc_video02.width=1360;
                mc_video02.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 2 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel3(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {           
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 3 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video03);
                mc_video03.x=340; 
                mc_video03.y=227;
                mc_video03.width=1360;
                mc_video03.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 3 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel4(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 4 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video04);
                mc_video04.x=340; 
                mc_video04.y=227;
                mc_video04.width=1360;
                mc_video04.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 4 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel5(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 5 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video05);
                mc_video05.x=340; 
                mc_video05.y=227;
                mc_video05.width=1360;
                mc_video05.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 5 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel6(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 6 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video06);
                mc_video06.x=340; 
                mc_video06.y=227;
                mc_video06.width=1360;
                mc_video06.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 6 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel7(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 7 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video07);
                mc_video07.x=340; 
                mc_video07.y=227;
                mc_video07.width=1360;
                mc_video07.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 7 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel8(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 8 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video08);
                mc_video08.x=340; 
                mc_video08.y=227;
                mc_video08.width=1360;
                mc_video08.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 8 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }

        function speel9(evtObj:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            if (filmAan == false) 
            {
                trace("knop 9 werkt");

                addChild(mc_video09);
                mc_video09.x=340; 
                mc_video09.y=227;
                mc_video09.width=1360;
                mc_video09.height=1060;

                filmAan = true;
            }
            else
            {
                trace("knop 9 uitgeschakeld");
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
```

And this is my video01.as

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class video01 extends MovieClip
{
    public function video01()
    {
        trace("movieclip 1 geladen");
        btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, terug);
    }

    public function terug(evt:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("knop ingedrukt");
        this.parent.removeChild(this);  

    }
}
}
```

How exactly do I change the var in the Main.as from the video01 class??

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `video01` class is a child of the Main class.  so you can use `parent` keyword to access the `Main` class.  You'll need to cast parent in order to not throw a compiler error:

From your video01 class:

```
 Main(parent).filmAan = false;
```

Comment: thx, but when I do that im getting this error: Main.as, Line 33 1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

Comment: you're getting that error because you're defining that variable inside of a function,  move `public var filmAan = false;` outside of the function it's in to make it a class scope variable